# Stop WebPack from replacing all instances of process.env.VARNAME for a AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, webpack, environment-variables

I have a JavaScript AWS Lambda function that I'm WebPacking before deployment. The problem I'm seeing is that all process.env.VARNAME within my app are being replaced with static values instead of remaining variables for the Lambda environmental variables to be used at runtime.

Based on my research, I think this is related to the default behavior of the DefinePlugin, but I'm unsure on how to disable the DefinePlugin. Anyone know how to fix this?

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin  = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        entry: './src/lib/index.js',
    },
    target: 'node',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
        fallback: {
            "fs": false,
            "tls": false,
            "net": false,
            "dns": false,
            "child_process": false,
            "dtrace-provider": false
        }
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                terserOptions: {
                    keep_classnames: true,
                    keep_fnames: true
                }
            })
        ]
    },
    output: {
        library: {
            type: 'commonjs-static'
        },
        filename: "lib.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        chunkFormat: 'commonjs'
    },
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Comment: What's the link here to AWS Lambda? 'The problem I'm seeing is that all process.env.VARNAME within my app are being replaced with static values instead of remaining variables for the Lambda environmental variables to be used at runtime.' is unclear.

Comment: It gives context to make it clear it’s not a web browser where we pack is typically used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured this out. The following is my webpack.config.js . Specifically, the plugin entry for webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env': 'process.env'}) is what I needed to avoid this.

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    target: 'node',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: false,
    },
    mode: 'production',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': 'process.env',
        }),
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you just set the values in the lambda dashboard and keep it static without the plugin?

Comment: The problem is that Webpack removes all references to process.env, so the code will no longer look to the environmental variable for the value.

Comment: that is bizarre! I've luckily never had my webpack remove references to process.env before unless I added a plugin to overwrite the references. I'm glad your solution worked for you!

Comment: IIRC in my research, this was something that changed in later versions of WebPack; so it may be you're using an earlier version.

Comment: possibly! I haven't tried since v5.36.2